# Failure running Overtone and SuperCollider

Tags: linux, clojure, supercollider, manjaro, overtone

I can't get overtone to work with supercollider server, I'm following the getting started guide at https://github.com/overtone/overtone/wiki/Getting-Started, I've got Jack audio server running through qjackctl, then I ran SuperCollider with `scsynth -u 8888` which produced the following output:

```
Found 12 LADSPA plugins
JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 48000.000000, driver's block size = 1024
SuperCollider 3 server ready.
Zeroconf: registered service 'SuperCollider'
```

then in the clojure repl I connect to SC server:

```
(connect-external-server 8888)
```

then when I run `(definst foo [] (saw 220))`
I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: deref! timeout 
error. Dereference took longer than 5000 ms whilst blocking until the 
following node has completed loading: #<synth-group[loading]: Inst foo 
Container 41>, compiling:(form-init1483192646581877285.clj:131:7)
```

and scsynth outputs `FAILURE IN SERVER /g_new Group 31 not found`
also if I try `(demo (sin-osc))` I get the error `FAILURE IN SERVER /s_new Group 7 not found`
although if I run using sclang:

```
s.boot;
{ SinOsc.ar(440, 0, 0.2) }.play;
```

it does produce a sound.
I'm running Manjaro Linux using the Linux 4.9.27 real time Manjaro kernel
and an HDA Intel PCH sound card.